# How can I have complex formula field in a saved search

Tags: netsuite

I am new to Netsuite. I would like to compute a complex grouped result field in a saved search, say, average(price) * max(amount).

I known SQL, and something called formula in Netsuite. I have tried composing a formula to compute it, but failed.

Is it possible to compute such a complex filed with formula? If not, how ? Javascript custom code? Please give me a little hint, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On the "Results" tab of the custom search, select the fields you want to retrieve the Average and Max value, and then on the "Summary type" you select Average or Maximum depending the field.

Then you add another field which will be a "Formula (numeric)" and on the "Formula" column you put

```
{averageField} * {maxField}
```

There's a pop-up that helps you with that.

```
- Hope I was clear, good luck.

- Also I hope I answered on time.
```